# Eclipse finds Java from CMD prompt but not from desktop click

Tags: java, eclipse

I have multiple versions of Java installed on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit system. In order to install

**Eclipse Java 2018-12**

I have had to install the **Java 11 JDK** from the Oracle website. Despite setting **JAVA_HOME** and updating PATH in environment variables the only way to install and also run this version of Eclipse was to open a command prompt and

```
C:>set path=c:\program files\java\jdk11.0.1\bin
```

and then run Eclipse installer or installed instance.

The problem persists if I reboot my computer.

I want to be able to start eclipse by simply clicking on the desktop icon link.
The error I get when I try to run eclipse from the desktop link is:

Version **1.7.0_79** of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.8 out greater is required.

My `C:\Program Files\Java\`

contains folders

- jdk1.0.7_79
- jdk-11.0.1
- jre7

I think I need all of these because I have some programs which I think retire java 7 so I don't think uninstalling java 7 is an option and don't think java 11 would replace it, or should I just get rid of java 7, is that what's causing the problem despite environment variables set correctly?

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you update PATH in env. variables?

Comment: From a standard account I entered the administrator password, added a semicolon, and the path jdk-11.0.1 folder''s bin directory, and there is no other JDK there.

Comment: Are you sure the PATH contains only one version  of Java (11)?

Comment: In the `eclipse.ini` before the line `-vmargs` you have to add the two line `-vm` and `C:\program files\java\jdk11.0.1\bin\javaw.exe`: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system was running C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe

I fixed it by adding the Java 11 bin directory at the beginning of the Path environment variable instead of at the end of the string, separated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Add `c:\program files\java\jdk11.0.1\bin` to your Windows Environment `PATH`

Comment: Did that, with a hyphen before the 11.

Answer (score 0):

First set JAVA_HOME then update path in environmental, refer screenshots attached.
[image: Environement setting for **JAVA_HOME**]

[image: Path setting in environment]